# Manipulating DateTime and TimeDelta objects in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am wondering how to manipulate Datetime and Time delta objects. I am writing a game where different planets have different timescales. And I was wondering how it might be possible to mod datetime objects.

For example if I have a date time object - some past datetime object I was wondering if it was possible to know how many times 6 hours might into the different and what the remainder in minutes was?

For example...

```
now = datetime.now()
then = some datetime object
diff = now - then
num 6 hour blocks = diff / 6 (rounded down)
minutes = diff % 6
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you better explain your question please. Write pseudo code, or show what you have tried.

Comment: or i guess another way of phrasing it would be is there a way to deal with timedelta objects as doubles or floats?

Comment: You might also want to experiment with creating your own datetime class. Depends how you model your universe but it might be simpler to just work with a constant second and then each planet would have a number of seconds per rotation (day/night cycle) and a number of seconds per trip around the local star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

timedelta objects have a total_seconds method in Python 2.7. So you could use that to work it out. You get a timedelta object back when you subtract one datetime object from another.

```
from datetime import timedelta

minutes = 60
hours = 60 * minutes
days = 24 * hours

diff = timedelta(days=6)

days_in_the_past = int(diff.total_seconds() / days)
hours_remainder = diff.total_seconds() % days

hours_in_the_past = int(diff.total_seconds() / hours)
seconds_remainder = diff.total_seconds() % hours
```

Is that pretty much what you wanted to do? If you are using an older version of Python then you could define a function that did the same thing as the total_seconds method like this:

```
def total_seconds(timedelta_object):
    return timedelta_object.days * 86400 + timedelta_object.seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

`timedelta` objects only have `days`, `seconds` and `microseconds` fields, so I guess for hours and minutes you'll have to use `seconds`:

```py
num_blocks = diff.seconds//(6*3600)
minutes = (diff.seconds%(6*3600))//60
```