# unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'

Tags: python, datetime

My python code is as below:

```
if ( delta % 24 == 0):
    print "ONE DAY "
```

It gives error as TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'

```
delta is of type datetime.timedelta
```

Please share your inputs to fix this error.
Using pyton 2.7 due to project requirement

Comment: What do you expect `delta % 24` to do? Evidently DateTimes don't support modulo with an integer.

Comment: Isn't the error message all the explanation you need?

Comment: @Carcigenicate  I am finding out end of one day using modulo operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` doesn't support modulo, thus the error you see.

This [Python modulo support for datetime](https://gist.github.com/treyhunner/6218526) exists though.

---

Moreover, you could cast the second operand, so that the error goes away:

```
if ( ( d % timedelta(minutes = 24) ) == 0):
     print("ONE DAY")
```

which works in Python 3.6.1.

EDIT:

This won't work for Python 2.7.0, which was edited to OP's question. In that case, this may help: [Manipulating DateTime and TimeDelta objects in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972570/manipulating-datetime-and-timedelta-objects-in-python).

Comment: Seems to be working for me on python 3.6.0, but only if both operands are of type timedelta

Comment: Hmm @con--, it doesn't for me in Python 3.6.1. Thanks for the upvote. Ah yeah, that explains it, but that's a *different* case, isn't it?

Comment: `>>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=19) % datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)
datetime.timedelta(0, 4)` is what I'm getting. I don't think it'd be too much of a stretch for op to cast both his args to timedelta

Comment: Using python 2.7 due to project requirment  after importing datetime_modulo.py . ` if ( ( delta % timedelta(minutes = 24) ) == 0):
   print "ONE DAY "  . `  This stills gives error as  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Answer (score 0):

What about reading the doc for `datetime.timedelta` ? Or even just test it in your python shell :

```
>>> d = datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
>>> d
datetime.timedelta(1)
>>> dir(d)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__pos__', '__radd__', '__rdiv__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rmul__', '__rsub__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', 'days', 'max', 'microseconds', 'min', 'resolution', 'seconds', 'total_seconds']
>>> d.days
1
>>> d = datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
>>> d.days
0
```

As you can see, you already have the information at hand.

Note that if you need other computations based on hours (not days), you'll need to use `delta.seconds / (60 * 60)` - for some reasons I can't understand no one ever took care of adding an `hours` or `minutes` attributes to `timedelta`...