# Python Pandas: How do I apply a function requiring an extended class (datetime)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, class-extensions

How can I use pandas `apply` for a function that requires an extension of a standard class (`datetime`)?

Specifically, I would like to import `datetime_modulo` from the excellent gist at https://gist.github.com/treyhunner/6218526.

This code extends the standard `datetime` class to allow the modulo operation to be applied to `datetime` objects, e.g.

```
from datetime_modulo import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
d = datetime.now()
print d % timedelta(seconds=60)
```

Now I need to `apply` this modulo operation to a pandas DataFrame column/Series, e.g.

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.values)
df['datetime_mod'] = df['dates'].apply(lambda x: x % timedelta(minutes=15))
```

But pandas is not able to detect the extended datetime class (unless I am just using it wrongly):

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try, as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999792/unsupported-operand-types-for-datetime-timedelta-and-int#comment78959736_45999842), converting the operand to `datetime` explicitly:

```
from datetime_modulo import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [pd.to_datetime('now')]})

def modulo(x):
    dt = datetime(year=x.year,month=x.month,day=x.day, hour=x.hour, minute=x.minute, second=x.second)
    return dt % timedelta(seconds=60)

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(modulo)
```

Comment: Excellent answer <filler>

Comment: @AmiTavory, Yours too for the pandorableness +1 :). Mine is more cumbersome but a little more generic as it will handle (for example) days / minutes / seconds to modulo by.

Comment: @jpp Fantastic, thank you, works! I slightly had to modify the arguments to timedelta (and change it to datetime) and have taken the liberty of editing your answer - is that fine?

Comment: @jtlz2, sure that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should try to avoid calls to `apply` in Pandas, as it is very slow. For example, if you're trying to find out the minutes within quarters of hours, you can use:

```
from datetime import timedelta
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': pd.to_datetime(['2071-12-12 10:04:44', '2071-12-12 10:30:44'])})
>>> df.dates.dt.minute.mod(15)
0    4
1    0
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for this - the number of rows is small in fact and the question did refer to `apply`. Much appreciated though!

Answer (score 2):

You are right, you are just using it wrongly.

See the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'Timestamp' and 'datetime.timedelta'`.

This error means you cannot simply write `x % timedelta(minutes=15)` and hope it can work. It cannot. `x`, which is an instance of `Timestamp`, doesn't know how to `%` a `datetime.timedelta`. If you want it to work, you at least need to convert `x` to `datetime_modulo.datetime`.

Comment: Good answer <filler>.

Comment: i.e. `lambda x: datetime(x) % timedelta(minutes=15)` ?

Comment: @Sraw Where is the proposed solution?